# Standard exam questions welcome here?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that the ["Error Detection"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7404/error-detection) question was closed today, with the reason given "Not a real question". And while the original question was both phrased and formatted terribly, it shouldn't have been difficult for users to understand the meaning. After all, it's a basic question type for many standardized tests.

So, my point is whether questions of this category (standard test type questions) are welcome here or not? And if they are, then what made this particular question unwelcome?

Comment: When I voted to close, it said "Seems true... [C]  ? the other".  I don't understand what that means, I'm afraid.

Comment: Indeed, since then it has been edited heavily by myself and others. I took it to mean that the OP believed [C] to be the correct answer, and wanted to know if more than one could be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about standardized test questions are welcome here, provided the other quality standards of questions are met. The asker should attempt to find the answer themselves first, and provide us with any research they uncovered in the attempt. At the very least, they should tell us which answer they thought was correct and why they thought so (or which answer their teacher says is correct, and why this confuses them.) Simply copy-pasting a question and using ELL as an answer service isn't acceptable, but there's no reason not to accept standardized test questions provided the asker has done their due diligence before asking.

For a more thorough explanation of what askers should do to prepare a good quality question, see [J.R.'s excellent meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).