# An emerging pattern of "research" close votes

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

Recently, and by recently, I mean during the past month or so, we've had an emerging pattern of **voting to close questions because they lacked research**.

More precisely, questions  used to be closed with this reason *only* for lacking context:

> This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to **add the research** you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or **provide more context**. See: [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Recently, the emboldened **add your research** has gained more prominence, to the degree of becoming a standalone close reason. To be clear, I've seen instances of questions closed with this reason that had nothing to do with context, or a lack of context.

I do not approve of lacking research being enough reason to close a question, because firstly, it's a slippery slope, and makes closing a burdensome task, when you just see a borderline answerable question and you close it because why not; and second, because real life doesn't work in a way that would make prior research a prerequisite to asking a great question.

Great questions asked by people who didn't see fit to provide noisy Google results for things they obviously know would take the greatest hit. Don't get me wrong — I endorse detailed effort, but only when the question benefits from it. And when containing effort becomes policy, naturally questions that don't benefit from effort, questions where effort would be fluff, would either have to be closed or noisy.

As for the question, **should we be concerned** about research-only close votes, or **should we continue** closing questions this way, because not much is lost in your opinion?

---

I didn't want to invoke the meta effect, but the comments and the votes made it mandatory for me to provide examples for this discussion to continue. Please don't alter the fate of the examples below (don't vote to reopen or close, or don't up- or downvote if you land on the question from this meta post)

#### Example 1:

- [What is the difference between "is mandatory" and "is a mandatory"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129526/what-is-the-difference-between-is-mandatory-and-is-a-mandatory)

This question obviously doesn't need further context in order to be answered. Sure, I don't like it the way it's phrased and it would've been closed if we had a homework policy, but the "add context" close reason is being used as an "add research" one.

#### Example 2:

- [Why is "can they" referring to "everybody" grammatical?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76268/why-is-can-they-referring-to-everybody-grammatical)

By contrast, this is a question I answered, which in principle, has nothing different from example #1. It demonstrates something that's seemingly contradictory, and hence interesting, but still, there's no sign of effort.

#### Example 3:

- [What does "feed the notion" mean in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128785/what-does-feed-the-notion-mean-in-this-context)

Again, no research demonstrated, but certainly enough context was provided, so doesn't make much sense to close it as a reason primarily used for lack of context in the past.

---

Possible solutions:

1. Come up with a homework policy, which is still itself some kind of a slippery slope and science sites have been trying to get rid of it.
2. Separate the context close vote into two categories of 'research', and 'context', each standing as a separate close reason. This might not be possible as there are a limited number of *custom* close votes available to moderators to modify.
3. Be more consistent with closing questions as lacking research and continue closing even older questions with an obvious lack of effort, to prevent double standards.

Comment: Also relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188067/280934

Comment: How about some examples you believe to be incorrectly judged?

Comment: I'm not certain they're incorrectly judged. I'm inquiring whether they are. I am probably the culprit of voting to close some of these myself. I would prefer not to incur unnecessary meta effect, and this could serve as a reference for future. (The two paragraphs in my post are merely my stance, and I don't believe them to be site policy)

Comment: This was actually [brought up](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/723) when the close reason was introduced, lo these many years ago.

Comment: Would you say this could use more research? Something else? [*When can I use “sum”, “amount” and “total”?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129326/when-can-i-use-sum-amount-and-total)

Comment: @user3169 that seems both too broad and lacking context, actually.

Comment: hmm... the accepted answer seems pretty clear.

Comment: @user3169 different people set a different bar for answering, and that question needs an answer to cover all possible contexts to satisfactorily answer it IMHO.

Comment: Could you give an example of such questions? I read you aren't certain they are incorrectly judged, but without two or more examples, the question seems quite abstract. I mean, it seems so to me.

Comment: At least, it would help in understanding your point. I agree that questions without any research effort aren't good, but I also agree that there is a limit to the research done, not because how real life work, but because the site is supposed to be used from users who are learning English. In short, what is your take on _research effort_?

Comment: @user3169, The question that you referred to should probably have been closed on the basis of "basic questions about meaning...", as the dictionary definitions make a better job of answering the question than  the accepted answer, which definitely lacks research.

Comment: @kiam okay, I guess it wasn't right not to try to invoke meta effect in this case, and I have a lot to say about what I consider research to mean, but I didn't want this post to get unnecessarily verbose for the answerers. Editing . . .

Comment: @user3169 edited.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because *I **do** think lack of research can be enough reason to close a question*.

Comment: @Fumble I believe lack of research is enough reason to *downvote* a question, not close it. I mean, it can be a good close reason with some other combination, but how are we going to deal with good questions that don't show any research? Wouldn't leaving them be double standards? (Thanks for commenting on the downvote BTW)

Comment: I think the key when reviewing a question is what is the OP trying to learn. This is EL**L** after all. For homework type questions (examples 1 and 3) with no additional effort by the OP, there is no learning effort. In addition, any answer can only guess at what problem the OP is facing. In my experience such answers often only do dictionary or basic research the the OP could have done with some effort.

Comment: @user3169 the crux of the problem here is there are some questions that you can immediately tell the OP didn't need to provide any research for because of the way the question is phrased, and when closing as lacking research becomes customary, people would start closing them more often. Those are also similar to interesting questions from earlier days of the site, which is why closing them will hurt the site. You could choose a custom close reason, but choosing a close reason that was used for something else is repeating the history, making close voting more subjective and harder to decide.

Comment: "repeating the history" because this was the same direction SO was headed to, and so has Chem.SE recently. And what's interesting is it's the very same argument every time, and even I used to make this argument myself.

Comment: I've seen cases where we seemed trigger-happy to close, but hesitate to agree that "you can immediately tell the OP didn't need to provide any research because of the way the question is phrased." Many questions could be improved with one or two clarifying sentences, such as the [feed the notion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128785/what-does-feed-the-notion-mean-in-this-context) question you link to here. Did the O.P. look up _feed_? Look up _notion_? Try to find other usages of _feed the notion_, or look it up as an idiom? Even if such searches were fruitless, I'd like to know.

Comment: @M.A.R.: It's not ideal that I have to downvote your question to express my opinion re the central question being posed here - ***should we be concerned** about research-only close votes, **or should we continue** closing questions this way*. If you'd posted brief "answers" for each of those options (and toned down your own position in the question itself), I'd have upvoted one of them *and* your actual question, since I think it's an issue that benefits from being raised here.

Comment: As a follow-on to my previous comment, I'd like to add a link to [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129715/what-does-ways-out-mean). I really appreciated the way the OP explained what they uncovered when researching their question. It's only a half-dozen words, but seeing _I found that "way-out" means "unusual"_ shows me two things: (1) we aren't being consulted before a dictionary, and (2) I know why the OP is confused, so I don't have to guess at the source of confusion when writing my answer.

Comment: @J.R. research is of course important, but the question really is whether lack of research is enough justification for closure. I would really appreciate if most questions did show research, but sadly, this is an unideal world where people don't show research while asking. Some people take it as granted that we don't need research, and others prefer directly asking to searching first.

Comment: I think an important point to make is that the question form does not include anything specifically recommending showing research first. 

For many people, ELL is a first port of call for any language questions they have, and I believe we should encourage that; if it is not obvious to users that it is recommended that they research first, then it may frustrate those who have innocently asked a question and found their question closed because they did not follow a process that they were not prompted to follow.

Comment: Closing is also a very final-sounding act, when really I would expect they would be prompted (possibly through comments of other users) to edit their research into the question.

Answer (score 10):

**The "Please edit to add the research you have done" part of that close reason is easy to abuse**, but it does have a purpose. I think that the "lack of research" attitude could be the start of a problem, so I'm glad you brought it up. However, we should not absolve authors of responsibility for the fate of their questions. If someone ignores guidance from the community, it's not entirely the fault of the close voters when the question doesn't get answered.

**We shouldn't ask for research because we want someone to prove that they have made an effort** before we will deign to answer their question. The primary **reason we need to know** what someone has found when they tried to answer the question **is so that we can write a good answer**. The research the author did shows how they're thinking about the question and what they already know. Another reason is to make it easier for the next person with the same question to find an answer here on ELL if they use a similar research tactic. If the question on ELL contains the search terms that didn't help the author, the next time someone uses those search terms, a helpful answer from ELL might show up in their results.

If the entire question is "What does this mean?" as in example 3, it's difficult to answer well because we don't know where the problem is. The "context" we're asking for is not *just* the words around the phrase being asked about. Context is also the answer to **"Which part is confusing and what do you already know?"**. It can be difficult for fluent speakers to see the issue with language that seems quite natural and obvious to us. It's like the classic duck/hare optical illusion:

[image: sketch that can be interpreted as a duck head looking left or a rabbit head looking right]

Fluent English speakers might be predisposed to see the "rabbit" in a sentence and non-native speakers might see the "duck". If the question is "what is the mouth in this picture called?", the answers are not going to be very helpful unless we know the person asking the question is seeing a duck. It might also help to know whether they are aware that the picture could also be a rabbit.

**Why do we close questions?** That's what we need to agree on. In my opinion, **we should close questions only when we want to prevent answers** to them.
We might want a temporary block on answers because the question may change significantly when we edit/clarify it. It might be a permanent block because we want to direct all answers to a similar "duplicate" question so that they can be grouped and ranked. We might want to prevent users from wasting their effort on a question that is completely off-topic for the site. We might want to prevent extremely low quality answers, like copy-and-pasted definitions from a dictionary. If you can't come up with a good reason why someone should be prevented from answering a question, then you should probably just down-vote the question instead of close-vote it.

There will always be some disagreement on whether individual questions should be closed. Also, since almost all of the community is human as far as I know, mistakes will be made. Luckily, it's easy to reopen a question.

Comment: @Nathan Some context that might help explain. https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10301/