# Why are most of my questions marked as "off topic"?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic-off-topic, closed-questions

I always refer my question source which is completely in text form

I know my questions related to movies but in text form for this you don't have see the movie

for answering my question, just read the synopsis which i include in the question is enough to answer my questions. no need to see the movie.

Comment: Could you please leave a couple of related links? Your most recent question isn't closed yet.

Answer (score 10):

Let's take a look at the following question:

[What is the meaning of "will fulfill a prophecy by bringing balance to the Force"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/103935/24861)

Here's the content of your question, formatted slightly to allow more natural block quoting:

> Title: What is the meaning of “will fulfill a prophecy by bringing balance to the Force”?
>
> [Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/synopsis)
>
> - Qui-Gon senses a strong presence of the Force in Anakin, and feels that he may be the "Chosen One" an individual the Jedi believe **will fulfill a prophecy by bringing balance to the Force**.
>
> My understanding:
>   Prophecy means "a prediction of what will happen in the future." Prophecy itself means prediction. What does the author mean when he says "fulfill a prediction?"
>
> In "by bringing balance to the Force," what does "Force" mean and how does it relate to prophecy?
>
> Small question: In the this clause in the above sentence: the Jedi believe will fulfill a prophecy — who is believing whom ?

The canonical page regarding low-quality questions is "[Please, everyone... details. Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)".

You, however, have clearly put some effort into your question. Here are some observations and suggestions:

1. You've linked to a source. Consider citing it as well. E.g. "[From IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/synopsis)" before the quote or "[- IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/synopsis)" after the quote, instead of just "[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/synopsis)".
2. You use the term "when he says ... prediction", but he says *prophesy*, not *prediction*. Try rewording this. Also, you mention the definition of *prophesy* (you should also link to the dictionary and cite it, e.g. [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prophesy)). It would help to also mention (and link+cite) the definition of *fulfill*. Once you do this, you might find that you have found the main parts to answer your question.
3. You ask about "Force". This is something specific to the context of a particular set of shows, and is not a broadly-used English term (protests of fans of the show notwithstanding). It's akin to asking for the location of Hogwarts - that only makes sense within the context of a particular series, and meaningless elsewhere; ELL.SE (even maps.SE, if one exists) is the wrong place for it. I'd expect that the definition of most proper nouns is off-topic here. A google search with the string "Star Wars Force" would likely yield better results. As J.R. notes in comments below, the [Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) is another place "well-written questions about The Force might be welcomed and on-topic".
4. You ask how Force "relates to prophesy". This can be taken as a Star Wars question or an English question. In this case, the sense that it is a Star Wars question dominates. If it is an English question, the responsibility is yours to make it clear. E.g. "Are *prophesy* and *Force* in apposition?" (No, they aren't.)
5. You use the term "small question" for something that relates to the title of your question. One might wonder what the real question is. The SE format is better-suited to single, well-formed questions.

Putting this all together, here's a start at rewording your question, assuming that your dictionary check for *fulfill* has already given you your answer regarding "fulfill a prophesy". Admittedly, it's a little contrived:

> Title: Who believes whom in "an individual the Jedi believe will fulfill a prophecy"?
>
> - Qui-Gon senses a strong presence of the Force in Anakin, and feels that he may be the "Chosen One" an individual the Jedi believe will fulfill a prophecy by bringing balance to the Force.
>     [- IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/synopsis)
>
> I understand the meaning of *believe* in the sense that includes two people:
>
> - 1.1 Accept the statement of (someone) as true.
>     *‘he didn't believe her’*
>     [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/believe)
>
> In the dictionary's example, the person responsible for believing is called "he", and the person who has the story is called "her". The 'person responsible for believing' comes before the word *believe*.
>
> In the quote above, we have "the Jedi believe", but it looks like the Jedi have the story about the prophesy. We also have "chosen one" and "an individual", so three parties in all. Who believes whom? Does the grammatical structure of the sentence give me this information, and if so, how?

Comment: Really nice effort despite OP's lack of cooperation

Comment: Superb answer. Regarding your Point #3, there is a [Sci-Fi & Fantasy Stack Exchange](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) where well-written questions about The Force might be welcomed and on-topic.

Comment: Thanks J.R. - that means a lot, coming from you! (I've linked to your *Details Please* post from ELU several times.) I've also added the scifi.SE link to point #3 in my answer.