# Can I post essays for evaluation here?

Tags: support

In TOEFL exam for example they ask you to write essays to test your English level, and I am preparing for the TOEFL. Can I post essays so users can evaluate if my essay is good or not, or they may suggest some changes. Can I do that here?

Comment: You may want to join us in chat. There are folks in our main room that may be able to help.

Comment: Here's the link to [chat].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such requests would fall squarely under the "proofreading" umbrella, and be promptly closed.

Thank you for asking about it first on meta.

Let me take this opportunity to reiterate why open-ended proofreading requests are discouraged on ELL. If they were allowed, ELL could quickly turn into a proofreading service, where the community is asked to examine and improve reports, essays, love letters, poetry, and schoolwork. That would probably drive a lot of people away.

That all said, if you have a **very specific** question about one part of your essay, you could perhaps ask that here, especially if you followed the [guidance](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/465#465) found in our ["Details, Please"](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439) post on meta.

#### In other words, this kind of general question should NOT be asked on ELL:

> **I'm practicing writing for my TOEFL exam. So far, I've written the following. Does this look okay? How can I improve it?**
>
> > *Maecenas pulvinar finibus sodales. Donec at sollicitudin sem, sit amet hendrerit enim. Proin in sapien ut ligula pharetra porttitor quis eu diam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque in tellus dapibus, posuere lacus id, pharetra metus. Aliquam scelerisque hendrerit tellus dignissim rutrum. Nulla posuere viverra sapien eget ultrices*.

#### However, this kind of specific question might be acceptable:

> **I'm writing practicing writing for my TOEFL exam. So far, I've written the following:**
>
> > *Maecenas pulvinar finibus sodales. Donec at sollicitudin sem, sit amet hendrerit enim. Proin in sapien ut ligula pharetra porttitor quis eu diam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque **in** tellus dapibus, posuere lacus id, pharetra metus. Aliquam scelerisque hendrerit tellus dignissim rutrum. Nulla posuere viverra sapien eget ultrices*.
>
> **My concern is with the word *in*, found in the fifth sentence. I keep trying to figure out if *on* would be better there. Is "Pellentesque *on* tellus dapibus" idiomatic? I found both phrases on Google but there were far more with *on* than *in*. Should *in* be avoided sometimes? Or does it depend on the context?**