# What sites and resources can I search before asking here?

Tags: discussion

Right now I have https://translate.google.ru as the only one instrument for translation. After getting no results from it for translation I don't know where to go and ELL is the only place that come in mind. But it seems like "too less research effort". What online resources for translation can you recommend?

Comment: The [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/9161) thread has good advice for how to add the right type of information. If you searched and couldn’t find anything, tell us what you searched for and where. It will help us understand why you weren’t able to find an answer.

Comment: Don’t discount normal googling! For example, your “friggen” question: you could have searched *что значит «friggen»* or similar (forgive me if the Russian is wrong). Also, you’ll want at least two additional things: a specific Russian-English translating dictionary (I don’t have one to recommend here, sorry). And a specific English dictionary: if you don’t already have a favorite, the site [onelook.com](http://OneLook.com) aggregates dozens of dictionaries and you can search them all at once. Over time you can see which one gives you the definitions that help you personally lost & use that one